# Does the spell effect of an alchemical device that misses its target still trigger?

Tags: savage-worlds, hellfrost

In the Hellfrost setting ranged weapons such as arrows can be turned into alchemical devices that trigger a spell when they hit. For example, you can have an arrow that triggers a Blast.

What happens if a projectile misses its target? Normally you ignore arrows that miss, but given the additional spell effect, should you roll deviation and have the spell go off as the arrow will hit something (the ground if nothing else), or is it assumed that the spell doesn't trigger as you missed the target?

Answer (score 5):

I went straight to the source and e-mailed the author of *Hellfrost*, Paul "Wiggy" Wade-Williams, who gave a definitive answer:

> The spell triggers but does so out of range, so nobody is affected.

I asked about battles in closed quarters, such as inside a building, where an "out of range" result wouldn't really make sense. He replied:

> It's much easier to ignore [the missile hitting something], as unrealistic as that is, in order to keep the pace going. Maybe the missile misses but isn't broken, allowing the user to pick it up afterward - no effect but his item isn't wasted either.

So the official answer from the creator of *Hellfrost* is: **the spell does not trigger if your projectile misses**. Although this might be unusual in some circumstances, it is the simplest solution for keeping the game moving.

Answer (score 0):

I would take this from the logically stand point. If these devices trigger on "hit" then it would be safe to assume they trigger on "impact". I would have the devices trigger and roll for deviation if they are AoE affects. (You never know, could wing their enemies and definitely make the magic more dangerous.)

If it was a magical affect I think you could lean more on the "it takes a specific kind of target to trigger it's affect." however since its an alchemical effect, it doesn't actually require magic to use only to make.